# "Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference" in PHP method

Tags: php, mysqli

Simple query to insert record in table but for some reason I am getting this error

> Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in  error.

I am not sure why. I tried almost 2 hours but not able to fix it.

```
$pid = '5';
$ip_add = '127.0.0.1';

$result = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO profile_view(profile_id, ip_address) VALUES (?, ?)");
$result->bind_param("is", $pid, $ip_add);
$result->execute();
$result->store_result();

if($result){
    echo 'Success';
}
```

Database design is as follows.

```
ID - BigInt - Auto Increment
profile_id - BigInt
Date - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ip_address - VARCHAR 100
```

Why would I get this error?

Comment: For what line this message?

Comment: You're sending PID as an integer, but it's declared as a string. Try $pid = 5 without quotes, or changing the i to an s

Comment: @clearshot66 It doesn't matter. MySQL is smart enough to convert a string to an integer. This isn't a PHP datatype issue

Comment: @Machavity then what is it?

Comment: You are clearly shortening what you are actually doing. If you hard code a value in the `bind_param` call instead of using a variable, you will get this error. My guess is you simplified the code you are actually using, and in turn, you hid the issue from us.

Comment: @clearshot66 The issue is with [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) (read the second Note block). He's not passing a variable, but the code he's got here has variables so it should work as written. I suspect there's more code we've not been given

Comment: @Machavity i am getting error on bind_param line as per firebug. regarding $ip_add i am using     $ip_add = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; i checked and found both variable have the value. But it is still failing.

Comment: got it. There was typo in $ip_add. That is the reason it was failing.